# Use ngModel with contenteditable tag

Tags: javascript, css, html, angularjs

I want to tight a model with a tag having `contenteditable=true`

However, look like ngModel only works with input, textarea or select:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Therefore below code doesn't work

```
<code contenteditable="true">
  <span style="color: red;">
    Hello
  </span>
  <span style="color: blue;" ng-model="name">
  </span>
</code>
```

AND

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/jLJCtcoZQMfhp80LpGfp?p=preview

What's the best way to do this? My goal is to format (style) some editable input/textarea but bind to model(s).

Comment: ngModel only works with input, textarea & select out of the box. but it can be extended and used with other things like with contenteditable, file input, custom radio buttons without an actual input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a few example of this in the wild, read and learn. There is some pro/con about each one of this.

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController
- http://bit.ly/1o4Kh2c
- http://textangular.com/
- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/528
- https://github.com/akatov/angular-contenteditable

---

Tip: [Show and Edit Style Element](http://css-tricks.com/show-and-edit-style-element/)

```css
body style {
 display: block;
 background: #333;
 color: white;
 font: 13px/1.8 Monaco, Mono-Space;
 padding: 20px;
 white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<style scoped contenteditable>body { 
  background: green; 
}</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Span not ng-model use this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.25"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <code contenteditable="true" ng-click="setModel()">
      <span style="color: red;">
        Hello
      </span>
      <span style="color: blue;" >{{name}}
      </span>
    </code>
  </body>

</html>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name='';
  $scope.setModel=function(){
  $scope.name="World";

  }
});
```

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for: (1) I dont want to click before bind (but its minor issue), (2) it doesnt have two-way binding (big issue here)